# Dynamic zoom level set so whole polygon can be visible in map area

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have below inputs to achieve polygon with different points on google map.

1. Center point: for ex: London new google.maps.LatLng(51.8100844,-0.02911359999995966)
2. Lat: for ex: 51.8100844
3. Lng: for ex: -0.02911359999995966
4. Distance(Miles): for ex: 10 miles

output same like this.
[image]

Map should be zoom out/in dynamically so the whole polygon can be visible within Map area.

if distance gets high then it will shown like this.
suppose distance i have entered 100 miles then

[image]

ultimately zoom level not reset even though distance changed.

Comment: So what's your question?  So far you've given us a list of your requirements... what code have you tried so far, and what's your problem?  Don't expect us to provide a fully-working solution to your brief, StackOverflow is to help you with specific problems you're experiencing

Comment: i already created this one which displayed in image above. now i want to create dynamic zoom level on this so whole polygon can be visible on Map area.

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Or post your code for the polygon.  Otherwise Dr.Molle's answer is the best you can expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `LatLngBounds`-object of the polygon-`path` and pass it as argument to the `fitBounds`-method of the `map`.